# Published page but it is page not found

Tags: custom-post-types, 404-error, wp-insert-post

I have published page with  post type `abc`, but the page is not found. If I keep post type, then it works fine. I insert post data and publish through query:

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_cpt_init' );
function my_cpt_init() {
     register_post_type( 'abc',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'abc' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'abc' )
                ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'abc' )
        )
    );
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}

function add_abc(){

   $my_post = array(
                      'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( $project_name ),
                      'post_content'  => $project_name,
                      'post_status'   => 'publish',
                      'post_type'     => 'abc',
                    );

                    wp_insert_post( $my_post );
}
```

Comment: Is `abc` a valid post type that you have registered?

Comment: I am just inserting  doing this $new_post = array(
    'post_title'    => $project_name,
    'post_content'  => $project_name,
    'post_status'   => 'publish',       
    'post_type'     => 'abc',
    'post_date'     =>  date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' )
    );

$post_id = wp_insert_post( $new_post );

Comment: You have to register a post type with [`register_post_type`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/).

Comment: Thank you my is custom plugin  and  my form form is different from Add new

Comment: I am just inserting  doing this $new_post = array(
    'post_title'    => $project_name,
    'post_content'  => $project_name,
    'post_status'   => 'publish',       
    'post_type'     => 'abc',
    'post_date'     =>  date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' )
    );

$post_id = wp_insert_post( $new_post );

Comment: function custom_post_type(){
  register_post_type('abc',['public' => 'true','label'=>abc]);
}

Comment: Please edit your question and add your complete registration code including the action you have hooked it to.

Comment: I have edited please check

Comment: where do you call the `custom_post_type` function?

Comment: no where because in my plugin folder  i have used custom add form

Comment: It doesn't matter whether or not you are using your own form, a custom post type will not work if it's not registered. If you don't want the built-in form visible, you can control that with your post type registration arguments.

Comment: can you tell me how to call custom post type function

Comment: Please tell me how to register and call that function

Comment: Please check i Have edited